# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table:

Tags: python-3.x, database, api

I was wondering if you can help, I'm trying to link a database to an API, whenever I try to run it it gives me the error

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: animals_information

I know the table has been created and it has contents as whenever I try to print it out it works but for some reasons then when in the code it comes out with the error if anyone could help that'd be great! The entire code is below.

```
import flask
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import sqlite3

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True


def dict_factory(cursor, row):
    d = {}
    for idx, col in enumerate(cursor.description):
        d[col[0]] = row[idx]
    return d


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return '''<h1>Animals Archive </h1>
<p>A prototype API to store animals data for our Code First Girl Project.</p>'''


@app.route('/api/v1/resources/animals/all', methods=['GET'])
def api_all():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('animals_information.db')
    conn.row_factory = dict_factory
    cur = conn.cursor()
    all_animals = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM animals_information;').fetchall()

    return jsonify(all_animals)


@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return "<h1>404</h1><p>The resource could not be found.</p>", 404


@app.route('/api/v1/resources/animals', methods=['GET'])
def api_filter():
    query_parameters = request.args

    id = query_parameters.get('id')
    name = query_parameters.get('name')
    size = query_parameters.get('size')
    fluffiness = query_parameters.get('fluffiness')
    grumpiness = query_parameters.get('grumpiness')
    friendliness = query_parameters.get('friendliness')
    intelligence = query_parameters.get('intelligence')
    mischief = query_parameters.get('mischief')
    cuteness = query_parameters.get('cuteness')

    query = "SELECT * FROM animals_information WHERE"


    to_filter = []
    
    if id:
        query += ' id=? AND'
        to_filter.append(id)
    if name:
        query += ' name=? AND'
        to_filter.append(name)
    if size:
        query += ' size=? AND'
        to_filter.append(size)
        if fluffiness:
            query += ' fluffiness=? AND'
        to_filter.append(fluffiness)
    if grumpiness:
        query += ' grumpiness=? AND'
        to_filter.append(grumpiness)
    if friendliness:
        query += ' friendliness=? AND'
        to_filter.append(friendliness)
    if intelligence:
        query += ' intelligence=? AND'
        to_filter.append(intelligence)
    if mischief:
        query += ' mischief=? AND'
        to_filter.append(mischief)
    if cuteness:
        query += ' cuteness=? AND'
        to_filter.append(cuteness)
    
    query = query[:-4] + ';'
    
    conn = sqlite3.connect('animals_information.db')
    conn.row_factory = dict_factory
    cur = conn.cursor()
    
    results = cur.execute(query, to_filter).fetchall()
    
    return jsonify(results)

app.run()
```

Comment: What comes to mind is that the table could have been created in another `*.db` file at another location...

Comment: The table and the api file are in the same folder in the same location - not sure if I should save them somewhere else or access the table in a different way? Sorry, I am a complete novice at this!

Comment: In my opinion then you need to consider the possibility that the table is not in fact created. You can have CREATE TABLE statement with a condition which will run without error whether or not the table is present like this: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...`.